# Ripple effect to whole parent view by clicking on RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ripple

I have a CardView, which includes RecyclerView inside of it. I try to make ripple effect on whole CardView (or whole RecyclerView), when the user is clicking on RecyclerView item, but the ripple effect applied only to item.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/list"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below attributes to your `CardView`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Run your app. It should work.

Comment: Can you post the layout that contain the CardView and your RecyclerAdapterView's layout.

Comment: First, why are you wrapping your recyclerview with a `ConstraintLayout` inside `CardView`. It really doesn't make sense. Remove the `Constraint...`(including its attributes) and copy exact code snippet I posted above to your code. Note, you're using `foreground`, I used background in my code.